# Do shareholders of OTC pink sheets "dark" companies receive financial information?

Tags: penny-stocks, pink-sheets, over-the-counter

On the OTC Pink Sheets, there are many "dark" companies (i.e. OTC Pink No Information). These are companies that have decided to stop filing certain documents with the SEC (e.g. Form 10-K, Form 10-Q). As a result, there is usually no publicly-available financial information about these "dark" companies. My question is: do the existing shareholders themselves receive financial information about these "dark" companies? Suppose I bought some shares in a "dark" company. As a (new) shareholder, am I entitled by law to receive financial information (in the form of a Form 10-K or equivalent)? If so, how do I obtain the financial information? Is it by contacting the company directly?

Comment: "Companies that do not meet standards can provide disclosure to investors directly to www.otcmarkets.com via the Alternative Reporting Standard" from OTCMarkets.com site

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY By definition, "OTC Pink No Information" companies are those that do not provide any public disclosure, not even via the Alternative Reporting Standard.